# How do I create a launcher / script that opens an URL in TorBrowser (from the bundle)

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, linux

If I do `tor-browser_en-US/App/Firefox/firefox-bin http://example.com` it opens in my regular Firefox browser. Is there a way to make a launcher/script that opens a link in the Tor Browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the `start-tor-browser` script and `vidalia` form the Tor Browser Bundle is not prepared to pass arguments to the launched *Firefox*. See this part of the script (near to the end):

```
printf "\nLaunching Tor Browser Bundle for Linux in ${HOME}\n"
cd "${HOME}"
# XXX Someday we should pass whatever command-line arguments we got
# (probably filenames or URLs) to Firefox.
./App/vidalia --datadir Data/Vidalia/ -style Cleanlooks
```

The last command results in launching *Firefox*.

It is possible to close the browser launched through `vidalia` and then to start it manually. Here is a procedure:

1. Copy the `start-tor-browser` script to `start-tor-browser-only`.
2. In `start-tor-browser-only` replace the line `./App/vidalia --datadir Data/Vidalia/ -style Cleanlooks` near to the end by `./App/Firefox/firefox -no-remote -profile Data/profile "$@"`
3. Make sure that the executable bit is set: `chmod a+x start-tor-browser-only`
4. Run the `start-tor-browser` script.
5. Close the browser window. Now just the `tor` daemon and `vidalia` are running. Processes can communicate through `tor` by using it as a socks proxy.
6. Start `start-tor-browser-only` *`http://your.address`*.

This way you can start the *Firefox* with parameters as you want. It will be started with the correct profile and correct environment variables: `HOME`, `XAUTHORITY`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `LDPATH`. Unfortunately the debug mode will not work and probably there would be several other minor catches and security implications.

Comment: For one, you won't be starting the browser with the environment variables that tell the Torbutton Firefox extension how to talk to Tor's control port. That means when you click 'new identity' in Torbutton, it won't be able to tell Tor to rotate to fresh circuits. So this is a fine hack if you want to play around with it, but it seems a poor choice for normal users.

Comment: Also, I'd encourage people to investigate this question in the context of TBB 3.x, which doesn't have Vidalia anymore and is simply the browser: https://blog.torproject.org/category/tags/tbb-30

Comment: It at least lets me avoid having to restart vidalia if I've quit the browser, so that's a timesaver. I was hoping there was a way to open an URL in the _running_ browser (ie. without the "-no-remote"), but I guess that's not possible yet.

Comment: @unhammer: If you want you can remove the `-no-remote` parameter in `start-tor-browser-only` then you can control the Tor Firefox browser by running `firefox` but there is a risk that you open some URLs through Tor though they should have been opened in clear and vice versa. Unfortunately `-no-remote` seems to be hardcoded in the binaries launching the first instance of Firefox.

Comment: On my system I get `Firefox is already running, but is not responding. To open a new window, you must first close the existing Firefox process, or restart your system.` if I'm running just Tor Browser, while it opens in the regular Firefox if I'm running that as well.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the [comments](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/84/how-do-i-create-a-launcher-script-that-opens-an-url-in-torbrowser-from-the-bu#comment98_92), 3.X series of the Tor Browser Bundle ships without Vidalia and now it's easier to launch it with a URL (or any other [command line option that Firefox would be happy with](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options)).

Here is a modified `start-tor-browser` script that will pass all arguments to Tor Browser while preserving environment variables set by the original script:

- [`start-tbb-with-args`](https://gist.github.com/gunesacar/3a49ef6a9daa546b2330/raw/9bab08ccef08dab75a4bee57b4b0bdbe24d5f73f/start-tor-browser-with-args.sh) (place in TBB root dir, same dir as the `start-tor-browser`, give execution permission with `chmod u+x`)

Some possible commands would be:

- `start-tbb-with-args torproject.org`
  *open torproject.org*
- `start-tbb-with-args about:tor torproject.org`
  *open about:tor and torproject.org (will open 2 tabs)*
- `start-tbb-with-args -search Tor`
  *search for the word "Tor" using TBB's default search engine (=startpage)*
- `start-tbb-with-args --debug torproject.org`
  *run TBB in debug mode and open torproject.org*

Note that, whenever present, TBB's `--debug` option will be processed correctly and excluded from the passed params using `shift`.

You can review the [`patch`](https://gist.github.com/gunesacar/3a49ef6a9daa546b2330#file-start-tor-browser-patch) (vs. TBB v3.5) which is quite minimal (only 13 characters were changed/added!)

**Please use the script at your own risk! Not sure about what kind of security/privacy problems this modification may bring!**