# How can I set a local page as my Tor homepage on a redistribute-able package?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I'd like to set up a local homepage on Tor startup.  The reason for this is that I'd like to set up a homepage that's not online (so I don't give away IP address on startup), but where I can have a login form that submits to my https website's login services.

But I'd like to set the homepage someplace like prefs.js and then redistribute the package to others who want to use these https services.

Where/how in the Tor preference files can I set the homepage locally, or where can I modify the existing Tor homepage?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a custom homepage by appending the following line to your [`prefs.js`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Prefs.js_file) file:

`user_pref("browser.startup.homepage", "torproject.org");`

The `prefs.js` file is located at the path `Data/Browser/profile.default/` in your Tor Browser Bundle directory. Please note the warning at the beginning of this file:

> `/* Do not edit this file. If you make changes to this file while the application is running, the changes will be overwritten when the application exits. To make a manual change to preferences, you can visit the URL about:config
>    */`

So, alternatively, you may change the `browser.startup.homepage` setting on `about:config` page and `prefs.js` will be automaticaly updated when  browser exits.

Comment: Thank you! Any idea how to make it recognize a local file? It keeps saying cannot start server at _filename_

Comment: One last question, sorry! I can link to a file by referencing its absolute path starting from the system's root directory. But how can I reference something local like "../newstartuppage.html" as the homepage. I need it to be a relatively referenced path. Thank you!

Comment: alternatively, if there's a way to modify the default homepage, that would work too.  Thank you so much!

Comment: You may play with the launcher script to load a local file as a homepage: http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/84/how-do-i-create-a-launcher-script-that-opens-an-url-in-torbrowser-from-the-bu/1109#1109

Answer (score 0):

open tor - hamburger menu opton (top right corner)
         - options
         - home
         - 'homepage and new windows' > dropdown > 'custom urls'
         - enter your url
         - goto any other menu option to save the change.