# Tor Browser Bundle: How to launch new-tab from command-line?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I can't find the way to launch new tab from `command line`.

```
/usr/src/tor-browser/tor-browser_en-US/Browser$ ./firefox  -new-tab
XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /usr/src/tor-browser/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/libxul.so:
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /usr/src/tor-browser/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/libxul.so)
Couldn't load XPCOM.
```

---

Finally, I'm trying to configure `Tor Browser Bundle` as a default browser for RSSOwl. There is such place:

RSSOwl http://www.rssowl.org

- Version: 2.2.1
- Build Id: 2013-12-30

Edit -> Preferences -> Browser:

- **Use the following external browser**:

> /usr/src/tor-browser/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/firefox --class "Tor Browser" -profile TorBrowser/Data/Browser/profile.default -new-tab

I'd tried everything, -new-window, `empty`, anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

I'd wager you're running Linux, so you'll want [`start-tbb-with-args`](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/1109/3731) presumably.  I'm unsure if that'll work when TorBrowser is already running though.  Just fyi `open -a TorBrowser http://eff.org` works in Mac OS X.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Tor in Windows (I do it in win7), when TorBrowser starts it have the remote tab disabled. The solution is, for each tab you try to create, send a call:

```
path-to-TorBrowser\firefox.exe --allow-remote  --new-tab http:\\www.yourfirstsite.org
path-to-TorBrowser\firefox.exe --allow-remote  --new-tab http:\\www.othersite.org
```

I use it creating a .bat small archive (new-tab.bat, for example).
To find the path to your executable, you probably know, in the link of the TorBrowser, right click, call properties, in the first path you have the complete path.

Answer (score 0):

Some important remark to [Francisco Barrau's answer](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/19853/34117):
If you use Pluggable Transports (e.g. connect via Bridges), it's need that browser started within its working directory(e.g. "Start in" in Shortcut settings). Otherwise obfs4proxy.exe / snowflake-client.exe will not be launched and connection to Tor network will be impossible.

So here is an example of how this can be done via cmd:

// Assume that Tor Browser installed to D:\Apps\Tor Browser\

```
cmd /c "cd /D "D:\Apps\Tor Browser\Browser" & firefox.exe --allow-remote --new-tab https://example.com"
```

P.S.
And if suddenly someone needs to open links in the Tor Browser from KeePass, then here is [my workaround.](https://sourceforge.net/p/keepass/discussion/329221/thread/2e629ecb/#f4c1)(Not great at all, but at least something)