# How do I open external links from within newsboat (RSS reader) in an already open instance of Tor Browser?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, linux, url

I already checked out a [similar question](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/84/how-do-i-create-a-launcher-script-that-opens-an-url-in-torbrowser-from-the-bu), but it's obsolete and didn't quite help me, hence I'm creating a new one.

I tried passing arguments to `start-tor-browser`, `firefox` and even `torbrowser-launcher` scripts as well as `firefox.real` executable found inside the main Tor Browser directory, yet none of it worked. Instead, it kept giving me an error, stating that Tor Browser instance is already running and I should close the existing Tor Browser process in order to open a desired link. I also tried creating a shell script named `test.sh` that would point to one of the aforementioned scripts and executables:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
$HOME/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/firefox.real "$@" &
```

then assigned the path to said script in newsboat config file:

```
browser "~/.scripts/test.sh %u"
```

and upon pressing 'o' button in newsboat it obviously kept giving me the same error about running instance of TBB. What should I do to resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with QuiteRSS. If I set the application's default browser to point to `start-tor-browser` then it can correctly launch Tor browser and open the link. However, if an instance of Tor browser is already running and I try to click a link then I get the same error as you. I am not aware of any built-in way to fix this.

Assuming you are on Linux, one workaround would be to use something like `xdotool` and `wmctrl`. You could write a simple script that gets the URL from the RSS reader as an argument and then uses `wmctrl` to check if an instance of Tor browser is already running. If it is, then use `wmctrl` and `xdotool` to simulate keyboard shortcuts to focus the browser window, open a new tab (Ctrl+t), activate the URL bar (Ctrl+L), paste the URL, and click enter. This would effectively achieve what you want. Something like this:

```
#! /bin/bash    

url=$1

# First, check if a window with the name 'Tor Browser' exists
# (we assume there is only one instance running, which is okay
# since it will not allow more than one instance anyway)
wmctrl -lp | grep 'Tor Browser' > /dev/null 2>&1

# Now check exit status of the previous command
case $? in
  1) # instance not found... launch it
     /your/path/to/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser $url
     exit  # quit the script
     ;;

  0) # instance was found
     id=`wmctrl -lp | grep 'Tor Browser'| awk '{print $1}'`  # get process ID
     wmctrl -iR $id  # raise the process corresponding to Tor Browser
     xdotool key --clearmodifiers ctrl+t  # open a new tab in Tor Browser
     xdotool type $url  # type the URL in the search bar
     xdotool key --clearmodifiers Return  # press enter
     exit  # quit the script
     ;;
esac
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, completely forgot about my question.

I've already written a five-line ugly script the next day I made the post here, but yours looks more thorough and appealing to me. Thanks for answering the question, by the way!